# Coinbase iOS client getting Error 403 on send_money

Tags: ios, coinbase-api

When i am sending BitCoins using the send:to:withNotes:withHandler: method , the failure block gets invoked with error localised description mentioning error 403 forbidden.

Comment: Can you point to [where in the code](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk) that method is defined?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 response from the Coinbase API usually means your API key or OAuth token is lacking the [required scopes](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#scopes) for the specific request you are making.

Based on the name of the method, it sounds like it would be the [Send Money](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money) request, which requires the `wallet:transactions:send` scope/permission.

You can check with permissions you have for an API key, or OAuth token using the [Show Authorization Info](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#show-authorization-information) request.